# Mono compatibility using CodeFluent.Runtime.Client

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform, pinvoke, codefluent

I runned a [MoMa](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) scan test on the [CodeFluent.Runtime.Client](http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-runtime-client) assembly.

I got warnings about 138 P/Invokes calls, 10 NotImplementedException and 14 [MonoTodo] markers.

Does anyone know what kind of trouble I can encounter using this library across Mono for a crossplatform project ? Is there a way to precisly know the features I could use and which I could not ?

**EDIT :**

The P/Invoke calls, for the zip compression class I'm looking into, are done on :

> CodeFluent.Runtime.Compression.x64.dll
>
> CodeFluent.Runtime.Compression.x86.dll
>
> CodeFluent.Runtime.Compression.dll
>
> kernel32 (LoadLibrary() for x86 or x64 dlls)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Why are you afraid of p/invoke calls. I mean, do you want to call the unmanaged code, or don't you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm asking if the p/invoke calls will work on Linux. The MoMa scanner pointed this out, shouldn't it be for a reason ?

Comment: What library are the pinvokes calling? Does the vendor claim Linux support?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good question, see my edit for P/Invoke calls. For Linux support, I actually do not know... There is no reference of this king of support in any way (good or bad) on the official website (that I can found).

Comment: The product is not supported on other platforms than Windows (that's why it's not mentioned on the web site). That doesn't mean some parts won't work though.

Comment: The pinvoke calls to kernel32 clearly will fail on linux

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you very much for this clarifying, do you think there could be a way to list every features that couldn't be used on another system than Windows ? Using a reflector tool or anything else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank for this precision, so the ZipFile do not seems to be supported on Linux.

Comment: Zip compression is easy enough on any platform. Why does the code use kernel32?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is a LoadLibrary call, I do not know if it is relevant... ?

Comment: Which library is loaded? Anyway, you have the answer. This library does not support Linux.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The x86 or x64 ones actually.

Comment: Those are windows dlls. So no go for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CodeFluent.Runtime.Client.dll` contains lots of useful classes. However some of them will only work on Windows :

- `WindowsUtilities`,
- `Authenticode`,
- `RegistryUtilities`,
- `TemplateEngine` as it uses Chakra (IE JavaScript engine),
- `Country` as it uses Windows's GeoCode,
- `ZipFile` as it uses a windows only native dll,
- `Icon GetFromExtension` as it uses Windows Shell,
- `GetTokenElevationType`

*This list is not exhaustive but contains the main classes.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this library uses compression code contained in these native DLLs. Those DLLs are Windows only and so at the very least, that part of the library cannot work on Linux.